# Finding Multiple Paths in 3D Data

Tags: python, image-processing, graph-algorithm, nearest-neighbor

## Problem

I have a 3d set of scattered data points. I'm looking for approaches to finding paths, as many as necessary, that satisfy a couple of constraints.

1. Going from point to point should happen through Nearest Neighbors, i.e. I would like to keep the distance between path points minimal.
2. Paths can share points but I would like to keep sharing minimal as well.
3. There is a planar face in the scattered data which I would like all paths to begin at. Where they end is not as important, but I would like the general direction of the paths to be away from the planar face and thus the path should only include a single point from the planar face.
4. All points should be a member of at least one path.

## Approach

NearestNeighbors from scikit seems to be appropriate for generating a tree that can be queried for nearest neighbors on a point by point basis.

**Q1:** How do I include a weighting scheme that will take the both nearness, in the Euclidian sense, and nearness in the sense that the path vector from $p_{n}$ to $p_{n+1}$ is close to parallel with the normal vector from the planar face? This is to prioritize points which will cause the path to move away from the planar face. I know the calculation I would use to test the closeness of the vectors, but don't know how I would include the result in the weight along with the Euclidian distance.

**Q2:** Is there an easy way to make $p_{0}$ always lie in the planar face?

**Basic Algorithm**

1. Number all the points and make a set from the point numbers.
2. Generate a path using the weighting criteria above.
3. Remove points in the path from the numbered set of points.
4. Discard a path if it doesn't remove at least one numbered point from the set.
5. Repeat 2 - 4 until numbered set is empty.

Any thoughts on this idea?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a graph algorithms case.

It seems that the way to solve it is to create a directed graph, where the nodes are the points that you have, and for each node, take the M nearest (choose your own) neighbors and create an edge from the node to the neighbor where the weight of the edge should be a combination of all your preferences.

For example, the weight can be:

```
   || Vi-Vj ||^2 * k
w=-----------------
      (Vj-Vi)N
```

Where Vi is the current node, and Vj is the next node.  k is the order in the list of nearest neighbors (starting from 1).  N is the plane normal.

The idea is that high euclidean distance adds a penalty, a node that is not the nearest also adds penalty, and the dot product in the denominator adds a penalty if the direction is not perpendicular to the plane.

Obviously, this is just an example and should be tweaked for your needs.

When you have a ready graph, you can run path finding algorithms on it (e.g. Dijkstra, Floyd, etc.)

When you select a path, and want to affect the selection of the next paths, you can take all nodes that were used and increase the weight of all edges that lead to these nodes.